# DensityHistogram, "Log" plot with specific binning not working in Mathematica12

Tags: bugs, histograms, logarithmic-scale

I have a problem plotting log with specific binning using the DensityHistogram. The following worked till Mathematica 11 but not anymore with Mathematica 12:

```
data1 = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {2, 3}, 0.5], 
   10000];
data2 = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{3, 4}, {2, 2}, .1], 10000];
data = data1~Join~data2;

DensityHistogram[data, {{-15, 15, 0.1}, {-15, 15, 0.1}}, {"Log", 
  "Count"}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 ChartLegends -> Automatic]
```

Any idea how to use the DensitiyHistogram with specific binning in xy? Automatic binning works, but it is not useful for my application.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this in comparing 11.3 vs. 12.0 on macOS. Adding bugs tag, it most certainly is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***A work-around:***  Use `(Log[#3]&)` instead of `{"Log", "Count"}` as the height specs:

```
DensityHistogram[data, {{-15, 15, 0.1}, {-15, 15, 0.1}},  (Log[#3] &), 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", ChartLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}, All}]
```

[image]

The issue seems to arise when the number of bins is large. If we change the bin specs  to get fewer bins the height spec `{"Log", "Count"}` works as expected:

```
DensityHistogram[data, {{-15, 15, 0.5}, {-15, 15, 0.5}}, {"Log", "Count"}, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 ChartLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}, All}]
```

[image]

```
DensityHistogram[data, {{-10, 10, 0.1}, {-10, 10, 0.1}}, {"Log", "Count"}, 
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
   ChartLegends -> Automatic, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image]

**Note:** `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` is added to stay within cloud credit limits for free Wolfram Cloud frontend.

Comment: Using (Log[#3]&) works as expected, thanks a lot!